# How to turn a pygam model into a SciPy BSpline

Tags: scipy, gam, model-fitting, pygam

I would like to get the best of two worlds: Scipy and pygam.
Specifically, I want to penalise the third derivative of my data using a custom pygam penalty function, and then I would like to use the result as a Scipy BSpline. The latter allows for easy calculation of the n-th derivative of the data.
Of course, `gam.coef_` gives me the coefficients of my model, but what are the knots?
If get close by using `gam.terms.get_coef_indices()-1`, but the result should really be identical to `gam.predict(x)`, i.e.

After a helpful comment by ev-br, we know now that we can get the knot edges by `pygam.utils.get_knot_edges`. Therefore, a promising piece of code would be

```
plt.figure()
res0=pygam.LinearGAM(terms=pygam.terms.s(0),n_splines=len(x),penalties=MyPenalty,lam=0.3,fit_intercept=False, basis='ps').fit(x,y,1/np.sqrt(w))
plt.plot(x,y,'x',zorder=10, label='data')
knot_edges=utils.gen_edge_knots(x,dtype='numerical')
knots=np.linspace(knot_edges[0],knot_edges[-1],len(res0.coef_))
plt.plot(x,res0.predict(x), label='PyGAM fit')
plt.plot(x,scipy.interpolate.BSpline(knots,res0.coef_,3)(x), label='BSpline from PyGAM parameters')
   
    
plt.legend()
```

Alas, the output is not very satisfying:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately B-spline methods are not standardized (I have developed five different B-spline fitting algorithms over forty years, and none are compatible with any others!), and close examination of the pygam and scipy results show that unfortunate incompatibility. First, the knots are either shifted and scaled (scipy splprep) or not (pygam), and second, the B-spline coordinates and coefficients are incompatible due to differing methods of computation. Although it may be possible to convert between them, it may prove to be almost intractable.

Another point is that if you want to use smoothing, splprep provides this (agreed, it may not be as easy and elegant to use as the pygam method).

Here is a method (using numerical differentiation) that may be suitable for pygam, compared with the spldev derivative for a set of tree growth data.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, splprep, splev
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math

from pygam import LinearGAM, s, f, utils
import pygam as pygam

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

Y = [5,5,5.045,5.234,5.369,5.558,5.693,
     5.819,5.864,5.882,5.882,5.882,5.882,
     5.882,5.906,6.074,6.398,6.674,6.842,
     6.998,7.07,7.082,7.082,7.082
    ]


plt.figure()
# Plot data
plt.plot(X,Y,'x',zorder=10, label='data')

# First, pygam
GAM=pygam.LinearGAM(terms=pygam.terms.s(0),n_splines=len(X),
                     lam=0.3,fit_intercept=False,
                     basis='ps').fit(X,Y)

knot_edges=utils.gen_edge_knots(X,dtype='numerical')
knots=np.linspace(knot_edges[0],knot_edges[-1],len(GAM.coef_))
print('GAM Knots')
print(knots)
coeffs = GAM.coef_
print('GAM Coefficients')
print(coeffs)
GAMY = GAM.predict(X)
plt.plot(X,GAMY, label='PyGAM fit')
print('GAMY fit')
print(GAMY)

# Second, splprep
tck, u = splprep([X,Y],s=0) # force interpolation by s=0
# where t = knots (scaled 0 to 1)
#       c = coefficients
#       k = degree of spline (default = 3)
#       u = An array of the values of the parameter.
new_points = splev(u,tck, der=0)
plt.plot(new_points[0], new_points[1], '.', color='k', label='splprep fit')
print('tck')
print(tck)
print('u')
print(u)

#Ynew = scipy.interpolate.BSpline(knots,res0.coef_,3)
#plt.plot(X,Ynew)
         #(X,label='BSpline from PyGAM parameters'))
   
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Derivatives, splev
dev_points_x, dev_points_y = splev(u, tck, der=1) # first derivative
plt.plot(u*23+1, dev_points_y/23, '--ro', label='splev derivative')
#u and y must be scaled and shifted

# Deriv, GAM (by numerical difference method)
XX = GAM.generate_X_grid(term=0, n=200)
#now do derivative(s)
Yprime = np.zeros(200) ## Y prime
GAMY = GAM.predict(XX) # fitted Y on XX
for i in range(1,len(Yprime)-1):
    Yprime[i] = (GAMY[i+1] - GAMY[i-1])/(XX[i+1] - XX[i-1])
# compute central difference on XX[i]
# now fix up Yp1[0] and Yp1[end]
#Yp1[0] = Yp1[1] # just substitution
Yprime[0] =  (GAMY[1] - GAMY[0])/(XX[1] - XX[0])  # forward difference
#Yp1[len(Yp1)-1] = Yp1[len(Yp1) - 2] # just substitution
last = len(Yprime)-1
Yprime[last] = (GAMY[last] - GAMY[last-1])/(XX[last] - XX[last-1]) # backward diff


plt.plot(XX,Yprime,'-b',label='GAM numerical deriv' )

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Data and fitted curves]

[image: Derivatives via pygam and splprep]

Comment: Thank you. Although I does not solve the problem, it is very reassuring that a correspondence between two BSpline methods might not be expected. As for your suggestion, splprep only penalises the second derivative, which I want to measure and thus better not penalise.

Comment: Of course you could always use my derivative routine on the first derivative in order to compute the second (and on and on.... until the the data cannot support any further derivatives). Also, there is a numerical method for computing the confidence intervals on a numerically computed derivative. It would be interesting to see a sample of your data, and what you have managed to achieve so far.

Comment: Great answer, and after looking into how to properly do numerical derivatives, and understanding why this code takes the middle point, I also realized numpy has already implemented all of this in a much more efficient way. 
In essence, the whole numerical deriv part can be replaced by `Yprime = np.gradient(GAMY, XX.squeeze())` without any loss.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/dswah/pyGAM/issues/265, pyfam fits uniform knots. The location of the first and last knots can be extracted via `pygam.utils.gen_edge_knots`.

Comment: Good hint, thanks. However, I was pretty much on the right track with that already. Updated the question.