# Calculation of Derivatives in pyGAM

Tags: curve-fitting, spline, gam, bspline, pygam

I would like to calculate the derivative of a fitted GAM model `a` at specific points in pyGAM. The model contains only spline terms, such that it should be effectively a BSpline.

Indeed, use of `pygam.utils.b_spline_basis` gives a matrix, which I can multiply by `a.coefs`to recover the pyGAM prediction from `a.predict`.
The idea was to use the analytic derivative of the BSpline to get the derivative. See [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-derv.html) or simply Wikipedia's BSpline article for more information.

I came up with this:

```
def GetGAM(x,y,err):
    
    if len(x)>5:
        gam=pygam.LinearGAM(pygam.s(0, n_splines=len(x)),penalties=__PenaltyD3,lam=0,fit_intercept=False)
        gam=gam.fit(x,y, weights=1/err)
        #print('done')
        return gam

x1 = np.linspace(0,50,10)
y1=x1**2
err=np.ones(10)

a = GetGAM(x1,y1,err)
x0=pygam.utils.b_spline_basis(x1,pygam.utils.gen_edge_knots(x1,'numerical'),spline_order=3,n_splines=len(a.coef_), periodic=False)
x=pygam.utils.b_spline_basis(x1,pygam.utils.gen_edge_knots(x1[:-1],'numerical'),spline_order=2,n_splines=len(a.coef_), periodic=False)
```

To recover `y1`: `x0@a.coefs_`works nicely.
To get the derivative I have
`der2=x[:,1:]@(a.coef_[1:]-a.coef_[:-1])/((edges[1]-edges[0])/(len(a.coef_)))`

I have also tried various variants of this, but could not get the solution (`2*x1`) to a satisfying degree.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a related question, and suggested a numerical method for obtaining the derivative(s) of a pygam fit to data. Here is the link that may meet your requirements:-

[Numerical derivative(s) of pygam spline.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897920/how-to-turn-a-pygam-model-into-a-scipy-bspline?rq=1)